# Docker Automated build downloading private jars from a Maven Sonatype Nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, docker, nexus, continuous-deployment

I am building a development pipeline. The Docker images will be created automatically after a successful and tested version of my java application be deployed on a **private** Maven repository (Sonatype Nexus).

Once my application is built successfully, I need to publish it in somewhere, and  Docker needs to have access to download it and create a container.

I thought on Docker accessing the Nexus Maven repository, but I did not find how can `wget` download a jar from a **private repository**. I did not found on Nexus documentation how I can pass authentication parameters to access a private URL. Does anyone know that?

PS: I also accept advice of easier solutions to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean by *private repository*? Do you have access to it from Docker while building?

Comment: Its a private Sonatype Nexus Repository. Needs user  and password to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered I can do it using cURL. Example:

```
curl -u username:password -o myapp.war "http://nexus.mycompany.com/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=com.company&a=MyApp&v=1.0-SNAPSHOT&p=war" -L
```

Where de `-L` flag is to cURL accepts redirect (301 response).

So, in `docker-compose.yml` I have a line like this:

```
RUN curl -u username:password -o myapp.war "http://nexus.mycompany.com/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=com.company&a=MyApp&v=1.0-SNAPSHOT&p=war" -L
```

Comment: Question, where in the output file does it go? I'm wanting to do something like this:

RUN curl -o / "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/newrelic/agent/java/newrelic-agent/3.30.1/newrelic-agent-3.30.1.jar" -L

Will that download the jar to the root of my docker image?

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to put passwords in your docker file?

Comment: You can use environment variables to store your credentials.

Comment: You could also pass the username and password during docker build like this:
--build-arg USERNAME=johndoe --build-arg PASSWORD=pass@123 
and access them in the Dockerfile like this:
ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maven

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging][:classifier] -DoutputDirectory=[target] -Dusername=[username] -Dpassword=[password]
```